# iOS 7 Disable user interaction like UIAlertView

Tags: ios, ios7

In iOS7 when the UIAlertView pops up, the buttons of the navigation bar change their Tint Color to grey and are not intractable. (Similar to the attached screenshot).

Is there any way to achieve these behavior without UIAlertView?

[image: An example screenshot from the AnyList app]

Comment: Just add a UIView with a black colour that has alpha set to 0.3f over the window.

Comment: This not resolve the problem to disable navigation bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable a button, like buttons on your the navigation bar, you can use the "enabled" property of the button :

```
self.cancelButton.enabled = NO;
```

or

```
[self.cancelButton setEnabled:NO];
```

Your button will be grey and with no possible interaction.

Comment: Nice solution. Disable buttons when the UIAlertView is shown and enable when it is dismissed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you want to do that you can use the following method.

When you want to enable the interactions, you need to remove the `overlayView`.

Declare a property like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *overlayView;
```

**For Disabling**

```
- (void)disableInteraction
{
   self.overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
   self.overlayView.alpha = .5;
   [self.overlayView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
   self.overlayView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   [self.view addSubview:self.overlayView];
}
```

**For Enabling**

```
- (void)enableInteraction
{
   [self.overlayView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: I'm not refering to the overlay view, I need to disable the Navigation Bar button tint color, same way as the UIAlertView does.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use UIView instead of UIAlertView to achieve this.Create an UIView add two Label for title and message and one button.

then call this view from where you want to show alert.

Comment: But how do you change the tint color of the navigation bar buttons?